# Parametric several variable limit

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For $\alpha>0$ and $R=[1,+ \infty) \times [1,\infty) $

Compute, if the limit exist:

$$\lim_{x^2+y^2\rightarrow\infty} \frac{xy^{\alpha}}{1+x^2+x^2y^2} $$ with $(x,y)\in R$

I managed to prove that

1)If the limit exist, the limit is $0$

2)The limit is $0$ for $0
< \alpha < 1$ (using polar cordinates)

3)The limit doesn't exist for $\alpha >2$ (evaluating the limit $\lim_{t->\infty }f(t,t^k) $ where k is a generic exponent >0)

The problem is that i can't prove anything for $1 < \alpha <2$

How can i resolve it?